# responsive HTML5 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have been searching about few details of HTML5 application but finding it hard or may be i am not searching in the right way. Basically i want to understand the new way of creating an application using HTML5 and CSS3 which will provide an experience of native application. Followings are my doubt.

1. How to navigate page by page. In typical web application every page is requested to the server and server will load the new page in browser with a refresh. In modern approch what is the way to do page navigation without page refresh effect.
2. In a typical web application a dynamic web programming such as asp.net, JSP are used to generate HTML files in browser. What is the modern approch do we still need to use the same way or plain static HTML files can be used and can be modified by jquery.
3. How the client server communication has to done so that page refresh does not happens. Can we use jquery for all the communication. Will it too much work for browsers.
4. How the HTML5 files are hosted. In server or each client has to have a copy of HTML files locally.

Any resources explaining this would be great.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't imply no refresh, and no refresh doesn't imply HTML5, this is just AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very generic, but I will attempt to answer it. 
1. **HTML5 is just a new version of HTML** which is still under [draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) according to w3.org. 
 HTML5 is still HTML and HTML navigates to other pages by requesting a fresh copy of the next page from the server, which the server actively responds. This will however flush the existing page from the browser and the new page is brought in. ( And yeah when the same page is requested again, either a cached copy in the browser is displayed or a new request is sent to the server and all the contents,tiny or huge, are reloaded). This is the reload part. However, you can use asynchronous services that AJAX has to offer using which you can request part of a html page.

> ***Ajax*** is a group of interrelated web development techniques used
>   on the client-side to create asynchronous web applications. With Ajax,
>   web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server
>   asynchronously (in the background) ***without interfering with the
>   display*** and behavior of the existing page.

2. Static pages are rarely used these days. However, if the site does not have too many user specific components or if the site only has static data to put in, then static pages are helpful, because loading the javascript stuff can be avoided. But then again, all modern web pages are dynamic.

> There are a lots of ways of putting dynamic content on the web like
>   the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach and Event Based approaches.

And just to give you an idea, **the new look is the one page look** where all the content in the site is displayed in one single page and there are multiple controllers that feed various parts of the page and all of it is combined into a view.
Have a look [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/web-design-trend-2013/) .

3. There are a lot of new js options these days with node.js and **angular.js** being the latest additions. [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/%E2%80%8E) is an excellent option if you want your site completely powered on javascript, however not many hosting sites support **node.js** yet. However, right now javascript seems to be the future.
4. This question is huge one, owing to the sheer lack of research from your point. Because, **hosting and having copies are two different things** because other than the hosting site and your client(that is the browser) there are lot of other servers which are put reasonably close to the client to serve pages on the fly, so that the file is brought quickly to the browser.

> So, in a sense a lot of websites which have huge number of hits have
>   layers of fast cached servers upon slow back-end servers to serve
>   requests quickly. Then there are also fast cached database servers
>   upon huge slower ones.

So, what I want to stress here is that this is a purely performance related decision that YOU have to take. So, if there is something you want to achieve, whether it be speed or anything else, there are a lot of options to explore.


Coming to the CSS3 part, animations part of CSS3 is still to be accepted globally. There are still users all over the world who have browsers unable to process CSS3D transitions( users using older versions of IE etc). So thats about it.

That said, these things are purely related to performance and HTML5 or CSS3 for that matter have no part to play here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery Mobile!

Basically jqm and other web mobile frameworks use Ajax to avoid any page refresh, with nice animations as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is more of a matter of how you want to pull data into your web app, from a server? then yes, it's gonna be an ajax request, and yes you will have to insert that into your html page, but again this doesn't mean your whole page has to come from a server.  You can basically have a three tier setup, server, middleman, and your frontend.  your middle part will have your html templates for your "pages" and will insert the incoming data from the server, and your front end will process and make everything happen.  it can be like a php/angular or jquery setup, or php/handlebars/jquery or javascript setup, there are many others.  Your page navigation again depends sort of on your framework setup.
2. Again kinda like the above.  Routing is the most common way of communicating to a server these days.  YOu basically requests data through different routes to the server and then process the incoming data -json perhaps-  in whatever template engine you want to present to your end user.  For routing, php solutions are the most popular, like slim or symfony.
3. Jquery is totally fine, angular is said to be much faster these days.  Handlebars is excellent for creating template pages.  Angular combines, qjuery, handlebars and some other stuff all in one.  Backbone.js another good one.
4. THis is an odd question or tells me that you need to research some more about the whole concept.  But think of in terms of frameworks and MVC type models.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you require a single page HTML 5 app, For page navigations you can use Jquery mobile.It implements it via ajax.If you require the experience of native application.(In mobile devices JQM can be a little slow)You would require to make some performance improvements in jquery mobile, like removing unused widgets,unused themes,using clever javascript for minimal page reflow etc.

For such apps,for code maintainability we require the use of javascript frameworks like backbone js,knockout js etc(You have a wide variety of MVVM frameworks to choose from).

For client server communication you can make AJAX calls.